# Why only some mysqli queries work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, angularjs, mysqli

I am facing a problem with mysqli select queries.
The table I am using is called participant and has the following fields:

```
id int(11) AI PK
name varchar(255)
surname varchar(255)
birth varchar(32)
sex varchar(32)
email varchar(255)
telephone varchar(32)
club varchar(255)
startingGroup int(2)
```

This is a PHP file (called select.php):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "$user", "$pass", "$db_name");

$query = "SELECT id, name, surname FROM participant WHERE NOT 0";

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
mysqli_close($connection);
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
```

which is later called by AngularJS in:

```
$http.post("select.php").success(function(data){
console.log(data);
$scope.newparticipants = jsonFilter(data);
console.log($scope.newparticipants);
});
```

The value returned by the first console.log is 'undefined' and by the second "". When I change my query to select only 'id' the whole thing works and data is visible. Any guess why it is so?

Comment: *"The returned value is 'undefined'"* - undefined "what"? *"Any guess?"* - Nope.

Comment: *"with UNION ALL and COUNT(\*)"*  - where's that?

Comment: you are have a column listed that does not exist

Comment: you also tagged as angularjs with no code to support the question

Comment: you might try changing `WHERE 1` to `WHERE NOT 0` -- I've heard that is faster  :)

Comment: (1) The value returned by this php script and console.loged is 'undefined'- that means the query returns an empty result.
(2) I didn't want to paste a long query not to keep the post clear. I wanted to say that other queries, using UNION ALL AND COUNT(*) work. But SELECT with more than one column doesn't.
(3) Hogan- no- the query does not contain any column that doesn't exist in that table, in that database.
(4) I am writing a web application in AngularJS, however, I didn't provide Angular code because the rest works perfectly.

Comment: Use the `mysqli_error` function to see what it says is happening. Update the question with your DB_scheme and the exact query you are running that fails. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Hogan- I just tried changing WHERE 1 to WHERE NOT 0. Didn't help. Suppose it is not a matter of performance. I hope it is syntax problem. I wish it was...

Comment: @Chris85 I just tried catching it with if (mysqli_connect_errno()) and if (!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) but there is NO connection error. I will update my question providing DB_scheme and emphasizing the query that doesn't work. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: It's not a connection error, it is a query error. Use the linked function.

Comment: @chris85 I used the linked functions. Please take a look at the updated post. There I include the select.php (including if conditions to catch errors).

Comment: Problem solved, please take a look at the answer below as it may happen to you sometime in the future:) Thanks for trying to help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

It occurred that in the database there were some diacritical marks coded in `utf8_general_ci`. I didn't have a clue on what's going on, because some queries responded correctly, some not. Selecting ids from particular range I was receiving a correct result. Selecting a range beside - I was getting undefined. I found it very hard to detect that the problem was with encoding(only some rows contained these diacritical marks).

If you are in a similar situation - check if your database has some non-standard encoding. If so define it in your code, just after opening a database connection, for example:

(procedural style)

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
```

(object-oriented)

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Thank you all for trying to resolve this problem.